# vxWorks Timers: Not able to call handler more than once

Tags: c, timer, posix, vxworks, rtos

I am making simple test in VxWorks with timer interrupt and to write number of times timer triggered, into a file using fprintf. But the problem is that timer doesn't run more than once.

I set the timer with timer interval parameter as you can see below. What do you think is the problem?
Sorry if it trivial question, but I am new to vxWorks and Posix apis, and from sometime I am not able to resolve this issue.

```
    #include "schdlr.h"
#define MILLION 1000000                 /* one million = 10^6*/
#define sec_to_nsec     1000000000      /* ns to s conversion = 10^9 */
#define MAX_ISR_READ 1000000    /* Numbers of sample to save -- 20170123
prova con 1000000 = ~50 minuti*/
#define timer_sec 0.00332               /* e.g. 0.04 seconds = 40 ms //// 0.00332
seconds = 3.332 ms*/
#define FILENAME "SchedLog.txt"
#define FLUSH_TIME 10.0
#define SIG_LLP_TIMER           SIGRTMIN
int     isr_idx;                        /* counter of ISR occurred -- starts from 0 and
increments at each interrupt*/

volatile float  clk_k,                          /* MY_CLOCK() value for the current sample*/
            clk_k_1;                        /* MY_CLOCK() value for the previous sample*/

/*clock and timer values*/
struct itimerspec custom_itimerspec;
timer_t timer_id;
clockid_t USED_CLK;
struct  timespec tv;
float a_n;


typedef struct TimeProbe
{
    float max_value;
    float min_value;
    float curr_value;
    float curr_mean;
    float curr_std;
    float prev_mean;
    float prev_std;
    unsigned int cnt;

} TimeProbe_t;


TimeProbe_t * ptp;
sem_t *sem;
const char* semName = "SCHEDULER_SEMAPHORE";




void init_timeProbe(TimeProbe_t* ptp)
{
    ptp->cnt = 0;
    ptp->curr_value = 0.0;
    ptp->curr_mean = ptp->curr_std = ptp->max_value = ptp->prev_mean =
ptp->prev_std = 0.0;
    ptp->min_value = 100000.0;
}




void init_data(TimeProbe_t* ptp)
{
    isr_idx = 0;
    USED_CLK = CLOCK_REALTIME;

    clk_k = 1000.f;
    clk_k_1 = 0.0;

    /*TimeProbe_t struct init*/
    init_timeProbe(ptp);
}

void fprintf_timeProbe(FILE* pfile, float clk, TimeProbe_t* ptp, int
flushRequestSent)
{
    fprintf(pfile,"hi");
}

void timer_ISR( int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
    isr_idx++;
}


void create_a_timer()
{
      int status;
      struct sigevent custom_sigevent;
      struct sigaction act;
      sigset_t mask;
      long long nanosecs = (long long)(timer_sec *sec_to_nsec);

      printf("Creating timer");


    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    act.sa_sigaction = timer_ISR;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);     

    if (sigaction(SIG_LLP_TIMER, &act, (struct sigaction *) NULL) == -1)
    {
            printf("sigaction fail\n");
    }


      custom_sigevent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
      custom_sigevent.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timer_id;
      custom_sigevent.sigev_signo = SIG_LLP_TIMER;
      status = timer_create(USED_CLK, &custom_sigevent, &timer_id);
      if (status == -1)
        printf("ERROR Create timer");

      custom_itimerspec.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
      custom_itimerspec.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
      custom_itimerspec.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
      custom_itimerspec.it_interval.tv_nsec = 500*1000*1000;


      printf("settime starts\n");
      status = timer_settime(timer_id, 0, &custom_itimerspec, NULL);
      if (status == -1)
        printf("ERROR Set timer");

}





void* thread_schdl(void)
{
    FILE* pfile;
    int toBeFlushed = 0;
    float   current_flush_time, last_flush_time;
    timer_t timerid;

    /*file stuff fopen*/
    if((pfile = fopen(FILENAME,"w+"))==NULL)
    {
            printf("ERROR opening file. QUIT. \n", FILENAME);

    }
    else
            printf("OK opening file\n");


    fprintf(pfile,"Starting log of scheduling test on VxWorks OS\n");


    create_a_timer();


    sleep(10);

    timer_cancel(timer_id);


    fprintf(pfile,"Timer times %d \n",isr_idx);
    /*file stuff fclose at the end - without this close it doesnot get created!*/
    fclose(pfile);

    exit(OK);       

}



int main(void)
{

        struct sched_param      myParam;
    int toBeFlushed = 0;
    float   current_flush_time, last_flush_time;

    printf("Scheduler Test Starts on VxWorks OS for interval of 3.32ms \n");

    ptp = (TimeProbe_t*)malloc(sizeof(TimeProbe_t));
    sem = (sem_t*)malloc(sizeof(sem_t));

    init_data(ptp);                                 /*init data*/
    Task_Schdlr = taskSpawn ("Task_Schdlr", 187, VX_FP_TASK, STACK_SIZE_T,
                             (FUNCPTR) thread_schdl,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);

    if((Task_Schdlr == ERROR))
    {
            printf("taskSpawn failed\n");
    }
    else
    {
            myParam.sched_priority = 187;
            /*sched_setscheduler(Task_Schdlr, SCHED_FIFO, &myParam);*/
    }

    if ((SEM_schdlr = sem_open("SEM_schdlr", O_CREAT, 0, 0)) == (sem_t *) -1)
    {
            printf("taskSpawn sem_open\n");
    }

    system("clear");
    printf("ciao \n");

}
```

Comment: Is your `sleep()` call getting interrupted by the first timer signal, causing the process to end prematurely?  Another possibility is that the call to `sleep()` in interfering with the timer.  Can you try something else to block on, like waiting for some input from the console?

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the suggestion, I had tried with while(1), but had the same problem.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that does not handle semaphores nor scheduling, etc so it only exhibits the problem your asking about.

Comment: The posted code is including some home-grown header file; `schdlr.h` but fails to post the contents of that header file

Comment: The posted code is long and rambling.  So I'll ask: "is the hardware timer setup to auto repeat?"  and "during the interrupt handler processing, does the code reset the 'status' flag so the timer can 'trigger' again?'

Comment: I see where the code is calling `malloc()` to set the pointer: `PTP`, but I do not see where that allocated heap memory is returned via a call to `free( PTP )`  So the posted code has a memory leak

Comment: please post the register layout (down to the bit level) for the hardware timer (or at least post a link)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewHenle again, you pointed out right about the sleep function interfering with the timer, (though can you explain why would this is  happening?). I introduced a while() loop, waiting for timer index to grow than certain number, and it does work as expected. 
Thank your very much for the comments above and for spotting problems with the code architecture with memory leak etc. I will make the code better.